# cannot view pdf to web view using file path

Tags: swift, pdf, uiwebview

i have an app to download pdf file. If the download completed it have a path like

```
file:///Users/developer/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F9AB746D-20C3-4333-AE70-2840538F4AED/data/Containers/Data/Application/861FA32B-06AA-4176-A499-B4BB8DF224C1/Library/Caches/pdffile.pdf
```

I try to view using this

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var path = ""
var receiveData: String = "" //this contain file:///Users/developer.../Caches/pdffile.pdf

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(receiveData)
    print(url)
    self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
}
```

the build succeded and no error butstill can't view the pdf file

what's wrong?

Comment: you have set receiveData = "" rather than receiveData= "///Users/developer/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F9AB746D-20C3-4333-AE70-2840538F4AED/data/Containers/Data/Application/861FA32B-06AA-4176-A499-B4BB8DF224C1/Library/Caches/pdffile.pdf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `NSURL` path, you need to use receiveData, because that already contain the path of the file, `NSBundle` is use when you have file inside your project directory.

```
 let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(receiveData)
```

Comment: still cant view the pdf file

Comment: Please edit your question with new code that you have try.

Comment: let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(receiveData)
    print(url)
    self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

Comment: oh i solved it using just `self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: receiveData))` and change `var receiveData: String = ""` to `var receiveData: NSURL!`

Comment: But you told that `receiveData` was string?

Comment: in 1st view controller i using `vc.receiveData = String(localPath)` so basically I change localpath to string (local path content is same with receive data)

Comment: after I change it to `vc.receiveData = localPath` and `var receiveData: String = ""` to `var receiveData: NSURL!` it succesful

Comment: Means `localPath` is URL, Then you can get build error previously where you have written `vc.receiveData = localPath`.

Comment: yep, localPath is basically URL but I change it to string before and get error